# AlarmManager for Android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In the below code, it is doing the main thing what I want so far:
- Repeats every hour at the same time

Can someone verify if or what I need to do to make sure of the following items?

(1) The alarm will eventually be based on days of a month.  As long as it goes off when they wake their phone up (to save battery).  It is not hour or minute specific.  Only day.  How can this be achieved?

(2) If the Activity is destroyed or the phone is rebooted, I am not sure if my AlarmManager stays awake?

(3) Lastly, This code is repeated every time the app starts (thus overwriting any existing AlarmManagers; is this a proper way of doing things, or should I be checking to see if an Alarm exists?

```
 for (int i : AlarmDays) {

        if (String.valueOf(i) == null ) {
            continue;
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) >= i)
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, i);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }

//  TimeAlarm.class
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String DebtName = null;

    nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = "Payment Due";
    CharSequence message = "Open App and Update your Balance";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ManageDebts.class);
    notificationIntent.getExtras();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Pay "
            + DebtName + " today!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
            | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    nm.notify(1, notif);
}
```

And in my application tag in my manifest:

EDIT:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <Application>        
  <receiver
        android:name=".TimeAlarm"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 </Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AlarmManager will *not* persist across the phone being rebooted.  However, it *will* persist across the application being killed by the Android scheduler.  Because of this, you basically need to:

- Store your schedule somewhere, and come up with a scheduling algorithm for deciding the next time you want an `AlarmManager` to fire.
- Each time you get an alarm, schedule a new one.
- Start the `AlarmManager` on boot, by catching the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have tried to implement your third bullet in the manifest and updated the code above towards the bottom.  Now I get a notification each time the device reboots, rather than waiting for the exact minute of the hour.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Sure, you have to do the calculation to determine when to schedule the alarm!

Comment: Doing more research, it appears I need to make a separate "boot receiver" to give out these calculations when the device reboots.  Is this correct?

Comment: Of course.  This is standard practice.  Create a broadcast receiver which listens for the boot message and schedules an alarm manager appropriately.