# Schedule AlarmManager event to happen a few days from now

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I have been playing with the `AlarmManager`in order to schedule an `IntentService`to do X task after a specific period of time. So far it works great, here' how I do it:

```
public static void scheduleNextRefresh (final Context context, long msFromNow) {

    Constants.logMessage("Scheduling fetcher alarm to happen within: " + msFromNow/(1000*60) + " minutes");

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);       
    intent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.EXTRA_ACTION, AlarmReceiver.FETCH_NEWS);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (msFromNow != -1) {
        Constants.logMessage("Alarm set");
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + msFromNow, pendingIntent);
    }               
}
```

That works well, so far; however, I normally only use small intervals such as 30 minutes, or a few hours.

Now I want to schedule an action to happen a few days in the future, and I'm curious as to whether or not it will work appropriately with the `AlarmManager`, or if it's simpler to use another tool to send a `PendingIntent` at X time.

Being that the smallest interval would be 3 days, and there may be a few reboots (I know I myself reboot my phone at least once a day) in the process, I'm not sure how practical the `AlarmManager` would be.

First, the logic of scheduling the refresh I am using is the same as posted above, the only difference is that I added some more code the the `BroadcastReceiver` in order to listen for `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` and re-schedule the alarms as appropriate.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    ...some other code
    else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Constants.logMessage("Re-scheduling alarms after boot completed");
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        //get the current interval we are using for cleanups
        long alarmInterval = Long.valueOf(mPreferences.getString("pref_key_ccleaner_interval", "259200000"));
        //get the last time in miliseconds that we set an alarm
        //Whenever I schedule an alarm in the IntentService 
        //I store the time in ms to know when it was last scheduled
        long lastAlarm = mPreferences.getLong(CacheCleaner.KEY_LAST_ALARM, 0);
        if (lastAlarm == 0) {
            //If no previous alarm is set, schedule it normally
            CacheCleaner.scheduleNextCleanup(context, alarmInterval);
        }
        else {
            //If there was an alarm set previously
            //The difference between the alarmInterval and the amount of ms ellapsed since last alarm
            //is the new time we will schedule this for
            CacheCleaner.scheduleNextCleanup(context, (alarmInterval - (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAlarm)));
        }                       
    }
```

I think that can do the trick, but I'm just curious as to there being a better way of scheduling events to happen several days from now, without having to worry about re-scheduling, or other events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rescheduling alarms on RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is the method I use (and has been working for over 2 years) and doing a quick search seems to validate it. [AlarmManager for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970229/alarmmanager-for-android).

Answer (score 0):

Alarms are not persisted across reboots.  You need to run at boot time to reschedule your alarms.  This is what the built-in Clock application does, for example.

As of Android 5.0, you might want to switch to using the JobScheduler mechanisms instead.  With them you don't need to handle your own boot-time execution or wakelocks or anything; you just specify the timing for when you want to run (plus any other interesting constraints like wanting to run only when the device is charging), and the OS takes care of running you at the right time.